Math expressions DCG in Prolog looping
I'm trying to implement a DCG for math expressions in Prolog because I wanna do the basic exercise of implementing a calculator in the language, this is the code I have:
lex(add, '+').
lex(sub, '-').
lex(mul, '*').
lex(div, '/').
lex(lparen, '(').
lex(rparen, ')').
lex(num, X) :- number(X).

expr --> [].
expr --> addsubexpr.

addsubexpr --> divmulexpr.
addsubexpr --> addsubexpr, restaddsubexpr.

restaddsubexpr --> [].
restaddsubexpr --> operator(Op), addsubexpr, restaddsubexpr, { Op = add; Op = sub }.

divmulexpr --> [Num], { lex(num, Num) }.
divmulexpr --> operator(lparen), addsubexpr, operator(rparen).
divmulexpr --> divmulexpr, restdivmulexpr.

restdivmulexpr --> [].
restdivmulexpr --> operator(Op), divmulexpr, restdivmulexpr, { Op = mul; Op = div }.

operator(Op) --> [X], { lex(Op, X) }.

I have 2 problems at the moment:

It's looping when I invoke it against simple examples like: addsubexpr([1, '+', 2], []).. And the statement it's looping into is this one: divmulexpr --> operator(lparen), addsubexpr, operator(rparen). -- basically it's doing expr -> addsubexpr -> divmulexpr -> addsubexpr -> ... or that's what I understood from tracing it.
For expressions like addsubexpr([1, '+', 2], []). it's giving an infinite of true when it should only return true once, since I'm not giving it any variables to work with.

I don't really know what might be causing those issues, because afaik the grammar is written correctly. If anyone can give me Insight about the reasons why, I'd appreciate it. In particular the second issue is pretty common in my prolog programs.

For point 2 - the structure of the DCG is wrong, hence the bad, recursive calls: addsubexpr --> addsubexpr, ... and divmulexpr --> divmulexpr, .... Instead of the awkward [1, '+', 2], this is more natural in Prolog: plus(1, 2).

This question is missing some basics - provide examples of expected inputs and outputs.

I messed it up, maybe from tiredness.
There's clearly left recursion in addsubexpr --> addsubexpr, restaddsubexpr. and in divmulexpr --> divmulexpr, restdivmulexpr..
Here's the corrected grammar:
lex(add, '+').
lex(sub, '-').
lex(mul, '*').
lex(div, '/').
lex(lparen, '(').
lex(rparen, ')').
lex(num, X) :- number(X).

expr --> [].
expr --> addsubexpr.

addsubexpr --> divmulexpr, restaddsubexpr.

restaddsubexpr --> [].
restaddsubexpr --> operator(Op), addsubexpr, restaddsubexpr, { Op = add; Op = sub }.

divmulexpr --> num, restdivmulexpr.
divmulexpr --> operator(lparen), addsubexpr, operator(rparen).

restdivmulexpr --> [].
restdivmulexpr --> operator(Op), divmulexpr, restdivmulexpr, { Op = mul; Op = div }.

num --> [Num], { lex(num, Num) }.
operator(Op) --> [X], { lex(Op, X) }.

